# Using custom SPRoleType

Tags: 2010, development, permissions, visual-studio, roles

Environment: SP2010 Enterprise, VS2012, c# Server-Side, full control of environment

I'm trying to assign unique permissions to an `SPItem` (a folder in a document library) through a console app on the server. I've been reading up on how to break inheritance and assign permissions [on this blog](http://www.thespgeek.com/2011/08/assigning-sharepoint-list-item-level.html) and combing through msdn articles like [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee535228.aspx). I have a specific custom role, `CustomContribute`, that I want to assign to certain folders programmatically, but none of the guides I've found tell how to do anything beyond the OOB roles (Contribute, Delete, Read, etc). A few places like [this one](http://geekswithblogs.net/juanlarios/archive/2009/09/04/giving-user-access-to-site-with-custom-permission-level.aspx) explain how to *create* a custom permission level, but I need a little help making the leap from that to actually assigning it to things.

Am I on the right track, or barking up the wrong tree? Any advice or links would be appreciated!

**Edit:** The `SPFolder.Item` property is probably what I'm looking for to add the role definition but I'm having issues specifying the folder in such a way that the property will fetch the item. See the code below for an example.

```
SPFolder oFolder = oWeb.GetFolder(folderPath);
SPListItem oItem = oFolder.Item; // Here it throws an exception, "The object specified does not belong to a list."
```

Is there a better way to select the folder based on the list itself, rather than through the `SPWeb`?

Answer (score 1):

Yes its a little confusing, the thing to note is that a folder is really a SPListItem so the permissions are applies at that object.

once you have created your role in the appropriate site or web. To be able to use it you need to grab it from the SPWeb.RoleDefinitions collection.

You can do something like, you need to add reference to System.Linq for following code.

```
//create SPWeb object thisWeb

SPRoleDefinition myRole = thisWeb.RoleDefinitions.OfType(SPRoleDefinition).FirstOrDefault(r=>r.Name=="CustomContribute");

//now get your user/group

SPUser currentUser = thisWeb.CurrentUser;


//now get your list
SPList restrictedDocuments = thisWeb.ListsTryGetList("Documents");

//create role assignment and role definition binding where you link your user to the permissions they have.

SPRoleAssignment roleAssignment = new SPRoleAssignment(currentUser);
RoleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(myRole);

//break permission inheritance so you can assign permissions

if(!RestrictedList.RootFolder.Item.HasUniquePermissions)
{
RestrictedList.RootFolder.Item.BreakInheritence(true);
}

//add permission

RestrictedList.RootFolder.Item.RoleAssignments.Add(roleAssignment);
```

Hope that helps please ignore case issues trying to type code on touch screen Interface is painful.

You would probably would not cannot set permissions on root folder but hopefully you get the jist

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've tried your suggested method but ran into a problem with the `SPRoleDefinition`, VS gives errors about it being a type but used like a variable, and that `OfType` doesn't take 1 argument. I have System.Linq referenced, but I'm not experienced enough with Linq to really know what's going on. The other problem is that I don't know how to specify a subfolder as an `SPListItem` object, previously I've always used an `SPFolder` object with the server relative url. Thoughts?

Comment: Read through the code a bit more and you'll see how to turn an SPFolder object into a SPListItem. the RootFolder is an example of an SPFolder object.

Comment: Ah I get it. Unfortunately the way I'm selecting the `SPFolder` object is through the `SPWeb.GetFolder` method, which doesn't seem to play nicely with the `.Item` property because there's no list specified. Is there a better way to select the folder? See my edit above for an example.