# Setting permissions on a folder

Tags: 2010, development, permissions, object-model, folder

2010, c# server object model

I'm trying to programmatically assign permissions to specific folders in a document library (see my original post [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/74143/using-custom-sproletype)) but I'm hung up on selecting a folder as an `SPListItem`. In the past I've always used `SPFolder` to create and manipulate folders, but I can't figure out how to cast that as an `SPListItem` which is necessary for permission editing. Any insight or even just links to articles are appreciated!

**Edit:** The `SPFolder.Item` property is what I'm looking for, but I've run into a new problem trying to use it. I'm picking the folder by building a string for its Url and then calling the `GetFolder` method on the `SPWeb`. When I then call the `.Item` property on it, I get the exception "The object specified does not belong to a list." I'm guessing that's because I called it off the `SPWeb` and not an `SPList`, but I don't know another way to select that specific folder. See the code below for an example.

```
string fullPath = parentFolder + projectFolder + phase1Folder; // This is a dynamically generated Url
//For example, "site/web/Document Library 1/Project Name/Phase 1"
SPFolder oFolder = oWeb.GetFolder(fullPath);
SPListItem oItem = oFolder.Item; // This is where the exception is thrown
```

Comment: Doesn't SPFolder.Item return you the SPListItem assocaited with the folder. Can you share your code?

Comment: You can have folder out of list or library, for example `web.RootFolder`.

Comment: In my case it was caused by invalid path for GetFolder method - I've had a space included in the path (which unexpectedly didn't cause SPFolder itself to throw exception)

Answer (score 1):

Use the [SPFolder.Item property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfolder.item%28v=office.14%29.aspx). A generic example:

```
foreach (SPFolder folder in collFolders)
{
  SPListItem item = folder.Item
}
```

Comment: That's probably what I'm looking for, however I'm having trouble calling the `.Item` property on it due to the way I'm selecting the folder to begin with. See my edit above.

Comment: try getting the relative path to the folder instead of the full path...starting after the web.